# Python code to multiply two columns and then create new column with values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am making a python code that first averages minute data into hourly data.  I then want to multiply the values in the two columns in the hourly data and create a new column with the multiplied values.  I am stuck on the multiplication step.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("inputfile.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
df = df.resample('1H').mean()
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1H"))
df.to_csv('outputfile.csv', index=True, index_label="DateTime")
```

**Data from hourly averages**

```
DateTime        current     voltage
11/1/2014 0:00  3.366184207 12.1758535
11/1/2014 1:00  3.361604775 12.1827364
11/1/2014 2:00  3.358049691 12.17596822
11/1/2014 3:00  3.354833198 12.1827364
11/1/2014 4:00  3.361096907 12.1827364
11/1/2014 5:00  3.361096907 12.1827364
11/1/2014 6:00  3.366344918 15.72258904
11/1/2014 7:00  3.419681019 1495.925115
11/1/2014 8:00  3.663316184 1870.538086
11/1/2014 9:00  4.369056237 1925.408667
11/1/2014 10:00 4.404945809 1938.888254
11/1/2014 11:00 4.711192238 1994.759897
11/1/2014 12:00 4.82263279  1995.281601
11/1/2014 13:00 4.428242773 1961.089536
11/1/2014 14:00 4.038091129 1895.686707
11/1/2014 15:00 4.04098199  1904.352924
11/1/2014 16:00 3.748518044 1852.646768
11/1/2014 17:00 3.397967499 1554.434254
11/1/2014 18:00 3.371380174 56.24243593
11/1/2014 19:00 3.375613815 12.18733199
11/1/2014 20:00 3.369686692 12.18239812
11/1/2014 21:00 3.367993271 12.18351949
11/1/2014 22:00 3.374089682 12.17048603
11/1/2014 23:00 3.367485231 12.18946266
```

I would like to multiply the current column by voltage column and create a new column with those values.

Comment: did you try `df['current'] * df['voltage']`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`df[newcolumn] = df['current']*df['voltage']`
will work.
You can name provide newcolumn as a variable.

```
def getPower(df, newColumn, numOfCol):
    for i in range(numOfCol):
        current = 'current#%d' % (i+1)
        voltage = 'voltage#%d' % (i+1)
        power   = 'power#%d' % (i+1)
    df[power] = df[current]*df[voltage]

getPower(df, 'Power', numOfCols) would create the column.
```

**EDIT**: This will work if you named your current columns like `'current1', current2',...`

Comment: Just saw this. Could you help me understand what `#%d` is and what can is the `'current#%d' % (i+1)` step doing please?

Comment: `%d`  (`%s` for string ) is to  mark the place you want to insert a decimal value in a string. The current method is `"sometring {}".format(obj_to_insert)`

Answer (score 11):

You can try something like this:

```
df['Power'] = df['current']*df['voltage']
```

Comment: this works however is there anyway to write this without typing in the column header and just use the column number to multiply.

Comment: @acb what do you mean?

Comment: sorry kind of confusing to word by my actual data has about 10 columns for current.  I would like to multiply each column by the voltage and create 10 new columns for power.

Comment: @acb do you have multiple columns named `'current'`?

Comment: yes for example there is current1, current2, current3 up to current10 however the names are a bit more complicated and they are different for every file.

Comment: @acb There you go, just made an edit. Not sure if it's the most efficient but it should work

Comment: What about the caveat: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy`

Comment: @BFurtado just do `df.loc[:, 'Power'] = ...` instead.